# Cookies not working with Trusted Web Activity (TWA)

Tags: trusted-web-activity

My twa works correctly but cookies not working.

I have created a remember me login, if I use the browser or pwa works fine and cookies are created. Is it possible that twa does not work with cookies? I have seen other twa's working with remember me login, how do they do it?

```
//PHP cookie
$timeCookie = time()+ 60 * 60 * 24 * 31;
setcookie('token', $token, $timeCookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

A Trusted Web Activity is just a special browser tab. Cookies works exactly in the same way as in a regular browser and no special handling is necessary.